# Checking tsp logs via ssh

Tags: server, bash, ssh

I'm using [task spooler](https://ttp://viric.name/soft/ts/) to run a process on my server. Is there a way I can check the logs via ssh? It seems that the commands are run by user/session, so I when ssh via terminal, I don't see anything that was run by the server.

- An API call to a PHP file
- PHP files executes the bash script

```sh
...
$command = 'sh ./generate.sh "' . $url_to_capture . '" "' . $thumbnail_to_create . '" "' . $webpage_size . '" "' . $screenshot_size . '" "' . $slide_full_path . '" "' . $image_format . '" "' . $slides . '"';
exec($command, $output, $result_code);
...
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

url_to_capture=$1
thumbnail_to_create=$2
webpage_size=$3
screenshot_size=$4
slide_full_path=$5
image_format=$6
slides=$7

tsp decktape reveal "$url_to_capture" "$thumbnail_to_create" --screenshots --size="$webpage_size" --screenshot_size="$screenshot_size" --screenshots-directory="$slide_full_path" --screenshots-format="$image_format" --slides="$slides" --chrome-arg=--no-sandbox --page-load-timeout=60000 --buffer-timeout=60000
```

I've installed [mpm-itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) to run the vhost as ubuntu (`AssignUserId ubuntu ubuntu`)  but I still cannot see any logs via tsp when I ssh.

I know the script is executing and can check it via `ps -aux`

```
ubuntu     45670  0.0  0.0   2832   100 ?        Ss   10:54   0:00
```

but when I type `tsp`, I have an empty list;

```
ID   State      Output               E-Level  Times(r/u/s)   Command [run=0/5]
```

If I run the command directly on terminal;

```
sh ./generate.sh "{url}" "{name}" "603x339" "603x339" "{path}" "jpg" "1"
tsp
ID   State      Output               E-Level  Times(r/u/s)   Command [run=1/5]
2    running    /tmp/ts-out.JXy3oe                           decktape reveal {url} {name} --screenshots --size=603x339 --screenshot_size=603x339 --screenshots-directory=/{path} --screenshots-format=jpg --slides=1 --chrome-arg=--no-sandbox --page-load-timeout=60000 --buffer-timeout=60000
```

Comment: Maybe try with `sudo -u`? ex. `sudo -u ubuntu tsp`

Comment: Look at `ts -h`, the help screen, especially `-l       show the job list (default action)` and `-o [id]  show the output file. Of last job run, if not specified.`